# Sending Message to Application from Server- Connecting the GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I try to implement an application with Google Cloud Messaging from http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html

```
Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);

                Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message", "message is created at builder")
                .build();

                Result result = sender.send(message, reGid, 5);
                System.out.println("result of message is "+result);
```

and consequently i get a message id and can see from console; but i want to show message at my device with a toast.

GCMIntentService.java:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
    Toast.makeText(this, arg1.getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

from GCM Advanced Topics:

*When a 3rd-party server posts a message to GCM and receives a message ID back, it does not mean that the message was already delivered to the device. Rather, it means that it was accepted for delivery. What happens to the message after it is accepted depends on many factors.
In the best-case scenario, **if the device is connected to GCM**, the screen is on, and there are no throttling restrictions (see Throttling), the message will be delivered right away.*

I can't understand what means "**the device is connected to GCM**".
How can device connect the GCM, connecting the internet and running the application from device isn't enough?

Answer (score 2):

Connecting to GCM depends on a few things.

1. The device has registered to receive messages - `GCMRegistrar.register`
2. The device has a connection that allows the message to be delivered
3. The device meets certain requirements for installed software that allows the delivery of messages - namely the Google API's - Minimum SDK 2.2

**UPDATE:**
When you send the message you receive a status response which if everything is ok will mean a message id. The device that sent the message will not receive the message unless the message was sent to that device (using the devices registered GCM id). The devices registration id is return following the call from the device to register.

Please note that with GCM there is no guarantee that the message will be delivered. It is normally very reliable but should not be used if delivery is critical.

Yes onMessage() is the entry point for a new message being received by the device.

Comment: 1. and 2. items are accomplished, but i can't understand 3. item. Device has internet connection and logged in with google account after that application is runned but i can't get toast message. Can you explain 3. item and is onMessage method true?

Answer (score 2):

You should follow this link to get answers of your all questions :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

you just need to implement client and server. I have implemented on my own PC and got running code.
 I have already tested on PC to Mobile also.

**Source Code is available.**  you just need to download and follow some easy steps.

I bet you will get your code running within 30 min.

Happy to Help !!

Comment: actuall i needed a java example like in the developer site sample how to modify a custom message with ` Message message = new Message.Builder().build();`